# dpdk How to use hyper-v tulip to drive the network card or hv_netvsc to drive the network card

Tags: dpdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfc47.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEaA3.png)
What do I need to do for the tulip driver network card?who can you help me solve this problem

For the hv_netvsc driver network card, I execute the following command: modprobe uio_hv_generic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQnh.png)